# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index, but the beans are already provided references to other bean

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configProperties' defined in class path resource
>
> [configuration-all.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?

Why I am getting this exception, how to resolve it and please most important thing how to debug `spring-application` on eclipse?

**Here is my code:**

```
public interface MovieFinder {
    public void findMovie(MovieGenere movieGenere);

    public void getMovie(MovieName name);

    public void displayMovieDetails() throws NullPointerException;
}
```

**TheaterOne.java**

```
public class TheaterOne implements MovieFinder {

    MovieGenere movieGenere;
    MovieName name;

    @Override
    public void findMovie(MovieGenere movieGenere) {
        this.movieGenere = movieGenere;
    }

    @Override
    public void getMovie(MovieName name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void displayMovieDetails() {
        System.out.println("Venue : " + this.getClass().getName() + "\nname : " + name.getName() + "\ngenre: "
                + movieGenere.getGenre());
    }
```

**MovieGenere.java**

```
public class MovieGenere {

    private String genre;
     //getters and setters

}
```

**MovieName.java**

```
public class MovieName {

    private String name;
    //getters and setters
}
```

**Client.java**

```
String allXMLFiles[] = { "configuration-all.xml" };
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(allXMLFiles);
        MovieFinder finder = context.getBean("getRightInstance", MovieFinder.class);
        System.out.println("Test");

        try {
            finder.displayMovieDetails();
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            System.out.println("bean creation failed at run time");
            System.out.println(ex.fillInStackTrace());
            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
```

**AppConfiguration.java**

```
public class AppConfiguration {

    String name;
    String genre;

    public AppConfiguration(String name, String genre) {
        this.name = name;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public MovieFinder findMovie_first() {
        if (name.equals("one") && genre.equals("sci-fi"))
            return new TheaterOne();
        else if (name.equals("two") && genre.equals("love story"))
            return new TheaterTwo();
        else
            return new TheatreThree();
    }
```

and **configuration.xml**

```
    <bean id="configProperties" class="com.config.AppConfiguration"
    c:genre-ref="genre_1" c:name-ref="name_1" />
    <bean id="getRightInstance" factory-bean="configProperties"
        factory-method="findMovie_first"></bean>

</beans>
```

**genre.xml**

`<bean id="genre_1" class="com.java.MovieGenere" p:genre="sci-fi" />`

**name.xml**

`<bean id="name_1" class="com.java.MovieName" p:name="one" />`

**EDIT** I have two other classes that inherit from `MovieFinder` and have same code as `TheaterOne.java`

Thanks

Comment: Posting code for `AppConfiguration` would be a good idea

Comment: @RC I made the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the error message, your `AppConfiguration` constructor takes two strings, **but** in your bean definition, you pass to it some beans (of type `MovieGenere` and `MovieName` (resp), that is the issue.

Comment: but if you see in `configuration.xml` i have passed two strings , still getting error

Comment: No you don't, xxx-ref is used to pass a reference to another bean, see the doc.

Comment: i provided values to both beans in `configuration.xml` now I'm gettng `NPE`

Comment: providing reference to other bean , how can it provide unsatsified dependency exception?... just asking

Comment: There's no magic, if injection cannot be done (because config is bad) then you get a `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` that's it.

Answer (score 0):

In AppConfiguration.java you have String parameters in constructor.But you are injecting Objects to AppConfiguration class through configuration.xml i.e

public class AppConfiguration {

```
String name;
String genre;
//Here you are injecting String parameters in constructor
public AppConfiguration(String name, String genre) {
    this.name = name;
    this.genre = genre;
}

//...
}
```

MovieGenere Object

```
<bean id="genre_1" class="com.java.MovieGenere" p:genre="sci-fi" />
```

MovieName Object

```
<bean id="name_1" class="com.java.MovieName" p:name="one" />
```

In your code you need to do Constructor injection with dependent object(i.e Non-string).

Rewrite the AppConfiguration.java something like this

```
public class AppConfiguration {

    MovieGenere movieGenere;
    MovieName movieName;
    //Here you need to inject Object parameters in constructor
    public AppConfiguration(MovieGenere movieGenere, MovieName movieName) {
        this.movieGenere = movieGenere;
        this.movieName = movieName;
    }

    public MovieFinder findMovie_first() {
       //remaing code
    }
}
```